# Does UIAutomator support hybrid applications?

Tags: android-uiautomator

I have just started to learn and use UIAutomator. I wonder if testing hybrid applications is possible using UIAutomator or it only supports native apps?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Well the best thing to do is "try it".  But, based on my experience uiautomator is not able to see the webview based components of android applications....I think Appium has been able to address this issue though.

Comment: UiAutomator can't do that. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554137/uiautomatorviewer-not-able-to-capture/38244258#38244258